# How to restrict bot to give response of bot command in private message?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I have created the bot but when someone DMs with the command in private message it gives responses in private message.

I would like to make bot respond to to command only when the user is in server and in text channel.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you need to add a line similar to this to your CommandHandler, this is how you can block any none Guild messages.

```
 if (message.Channel is SocketDMChannel) return;
```

This will return from the method as soon as the channel is a SocketDMChannel.

Comment: Added that in my CommandHandler and it works like charm.
Thank you @Twenty

Answer (score 0):

I've had to use this validation in many places so I extended the ModuleBase and placed all my validation inside it.  :

```
public bool IsFromGuildChat()
{
     var IsFromGuildChat = Context.Guild.Id != 0;
     if (IsFromGuildChat == false)
         throw new RequiresDiscordGuildException(); //custom exception 

      return IsFromGuildChat;
}
```

Then in the top of my command:

```
[Command("test")]
[Alias("t")]
public async Task Test()
{
    //validation
    if (!IsFromGuildChat())
        return;

    await ReplyAsync("This is only called from Guild Chat!");
}
```